# Trying to send mouse down and up events to a drawing canvas application/window in C++

Tags: c++, mouse, mouseevent, draw

I'm trying to write a simple program that will move the mouse cursor to an X,Y position on screen, send a mouse down event, move the cursor again, and release mouse to draw a line

I've tried using SendInput and mouse_events to some success, but not what I am looking for.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
tagINPUT inp;
tagMOUSEINPUT mi;
DWORD moveFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE);
DWORD downFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN);
DWORD upFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);

mi.dwFlags = moveFlags;
mi.dx = 5000;
mi.dy = 2000;
inp.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
inp.mi = mi;

SendInput(1, &inp, sizeof inp);

tagMOUSEINPUT mi2;
tagINPUT inp2;

SetCursorPos(1500, 500);

mi2.dwFlags = downFlags;
inp2.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
inp2.mi = mi2;
SendInput(1, &inp2, sizeof inp2);

SetCursorPos(500,200);
mi2.dwFlags = upFlags;
inp2.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
inp2.mi=mi2;
SendInput(1, &inp2, sizeof inp2);

return 0;
}
```

Very basic attempt just to move, click, move and release.

Basically, this works fine with regular user controls. It will highlight some text if say, Chrome, is the top window. I can move the x/y to make it  click buttons/user controls on screen...

This will also draw the required line in MSPaint IF and only IF the Eraser function is selected. If I attempt to use the Brushtool, nothing will happen. Same if I am attempting to draw on a flash window (http://doodle.no.de);

I've tried using 0x0201 and 0x0202 as my leftdown and leftup (these are both the WM_ equivalent) and they behave the exact same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mouse_event it is fairly easy to accomplish this task. This is the code I came up with, hopefully this helps.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <windows.h>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
int pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4;


    cout << "Enter x coordinate: ";    //starting point  
    cin >> pos1;
    cout << "Enter y coordinate: ";
   cin >> pos2;


    cout << "Enter x coordinate: ";    //ending point
    cin >> pos3;
    cout << "Enter y coordinate: ";
    cin >> pos4;

  SetCursorPos(pos1,pos2);
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0); //clicks on canvas
  Sleep(30);                                      //puts small delay between next click
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // holds down left mouse button
  Sleep(300);
  SetCursorPos(pos3,pos4);
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);  //releases left mouse button


return 0;
}
```